# Error in angle_model$edd : $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Tags: class, operator-keyword, r-s4

This seem to be a recurrent error message but solutions seem to be rather case specific for what I'm seeing  (I'm starting with R so every step is difficult for me still). I'm following the script for a estimation of density with camera traps and after finding solutions for every problem on my own, I got to this last one just at the end, and I don't know hot to fix it. The part of the script I'm following is this:

[Last section of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5bQU.jpg)

And I got stuck with param <- get_parameter_table(rad, ang, spd, act)

When I run it it says this:

*Error in angle_model$edd : $ operator not defined for this S4 class*

The same error occurs if I just run *rad*, *spd* or *act* alone.

When I ask RStudio to show Traceback it says this:

[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEQP7.jpg)

What could I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you cannot use the `$` operator with the `angle_model` object. You will have to find some other way to access the parts of it. Check the package documentation for any way they have provided, but failing that you may be able to use the `@` operator, which gets the *slots* (similar to attributes, but not quite the same) of the object.

Alternatively, you might be able to use the `[` or `[[` operators instead of `$`, e.g. `angle_model[["edd"]]`.